# Is it possible to send print commands to IMP MICR Printer by Inotech using ASCII codes?

Tags: vb.net, printing, imp, micr

I have a MICR printer from InoTech called IMP. The printer is installed as "Generic/Text Only" printer which prints RAW data. It has a MICR character drum which moves and impacts the codes.

Now i am unable to find a code on the internet which can help me in vb.net to print the code. I have another printer attached with it in the tandem which prints specific text on cheque leaves.

Is it possible to print using ASCII codes in vb.net? Any coding will be helpful.

I have tried to send a Windows Test print. The print comes in print jobs but does not print on printer as it does not contain those characters on its drum. IMP Printer shows "BAD DATA INPUT" on its LCD display!